# Request failed due to following response errors: - Could not resolve to a ProjectV2 with the number 2

Tags: github-actions, cicd

I am new to github actions so pardon my lack of knowledge. But I keep receiving this error:

Request failed due to the following response error:

> `Could not resolve to a ProjectV2 with the number 2.`

when I run this workflow:

```
on:
  workflow_call:
  pull_request:
    types:
      - opened
      - synchronize
      - closed
jobs:
  add-to-project:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Add PR to Project
        uses: actions/add-to-project@v0.5.0
        with:
          project-url: https://github.com/orgs/<org_name_here>/projects/2
          github-token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
```

- All of my repo settings allow read/write permissions and access to GitHub Projects board.
- My project URL is correct. I only edited the actual org name but that is the URL for the project.

When I change to the GitHub token to my PAT it runs, but why does the error come up when I use the default `github_token`?

Is there a reason the default GitHub token does not have access? I would like to be able to just use `secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN` to get my token to run.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Automating Projects using Actions](https://docs.github.com/en/issues/planning-and-tracking-with-projects/automating-your-project/automating-projects-using-actions):

> **Note**: `GITHUB_TOKEN` is scoped to the repository level and cannot access projects. To access projects you can either create a GitHub App (recommended for organization projects) or a personal access token (recommended for user projects). ...

That's why `GITHUB_TOKEN` doesn't work for projects and the PAT with `project` scope works.

---

You might want to go through [Automatic token authentication](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/automatic-token-authentication) for more details on `GITHUB_TOKEN`.